# MySQL get one record per group

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a MySQL table `targeted_refills` with columns: `id` (unique, primary key), `pat_name`, `pat_phone`, `rx_number`, `drug_name`, `qty_disp`, `last_date`, `qty_left`, `price_code`, `last_price`, `last_contact`, `doc_name`, `ehf`, `userid`

What I'm trying to do is list one record for each `userid`. The record I want listed is the most recent one based on the field `last_date` however if there is more than one record for that user with the most recent date then I want it to select the field with the largest value in the field `last_price`. In the rare event that there are two records with matching `last_date` and `last_price` (shouldn't happen but is possible), I really don't care which is chosen so it can be chosen off the largest value of `id` since that is unique and the primary key.

EDIT:

I've tried this query that I pieced together from another person's question:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM `targeted_refills` AS t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN `targeted_refills` AS t2
  ON t1.userid = t2.userid 
        AND (t1.last_date < t2.last_date 
         OR (t1.last_date = t2.last_date AND t1.last_price < t2.last_price))
WHERE t2.userid IS NULL;
```

and it does a reasonable job of getting where I want to go, but it's pulling a few more records than I want. I'm comparing now to see what extra records it's pulling and why. It also takes a long time to run.

Comment: You should you use a subquery, do you have a `SELECT` statement as a starting point?

Comment: [SQL Select only rows with Max Value on a Column](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7745609/1037210).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fetch the row which has the Max value for a column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/121387/fetch-the-row-which-has-the-max-value-for-a-column)

Comment: [So what have you tried so far ?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATED** You can tweak your existing query a little bit: you need at least one more join condition that prevent duplicates when both `last_date` and `last_price` are equal across several rows. Since you have auto-generated `id` you can use it to differentiate rows.

```
SELECT t1.*
  FROM targeted_refills t1 LEFT JOIN targeted_refills t2
    ON t1.userid = t2.userid 
   AND (
         t1.last_date < t2.last_date 
         OR 
         (t1.last_date = t2.last_date AND 
          t1.last_price < t2.last_price)
         OR
         (t1.last_date = t2.last_date AND 
          t1.last_price = t2.last_price AND
          t1.id < t2.id)         
       )
WHERE t2.userid IS NULL;
```

Or you can achieve your goal another way

```sql
SELECT id, pat_name, pat_phone, rx_number, drug_name, 
       qty_disp, last_date, qty_left, price_code, 
       last_price, last_contact, doc_name, ehf, userid
  FROM 
(
  SELECT r.*,
         @n := IF(@u = userid, @n + 1, 1) rownum,
         @u := userid
    FROM targeted_refills r
   ORDER BY userid, last_date DESC, last_price DESC
) q
 WHERE q.rownum = 1
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c5d06/1)** demo for both queries.

Comment: Thanks. They both seem to work (I changed some of the data in the SQLFiddle demo to match what I was trying to accomplish and the format of my data in case it helps anyone else) [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/71c06/1). It runs really slowly for me as it sifts through about 20,000 records. It takes several minutes to get through it all. It's on a test server though so I'll try it out on a "real" one to see how it does. Either way though, the few minutes of waiting is way better than the time it takes me to do it manually. Thanks again.

Comment: @user1678042 I'm glad I could help :). Make sure that you have indices  on `last_date` and `last_price`. That may help to speed things up.

Comment: DOH!!! That's usually one of my first steps but I completely forgot the indices. Now it's seconds instead of minutes. I literally face palmed. Thanks again!!!